# Scheduled Python scraper in Heroku?

Tags: python, json, api, heroku, scrapy

I wrote a Python scraper using scrapy. The folder structure has a "master" script that runs 2 spiders from a subfolder. Locally I can run `python scraper.py`, and the script does all the scraping, saving the content into a `.json` file located in another subfolder called "api".

What I'm aiming to do, is deploy the "app" on Heroku so I could use the scraping results as an api by typing `appname.herokuapp.com/api/results.json`. I would use Heroku Scheduler to run the script every x minutes/hours, and it should delete the old `results.json` and replace it with the new one. What would be the easiest way to go about doing this?

Comment: use the [heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to set up how to run your application, you'll have to define some environment variables so your project could be found like the `PYTHONPATH` but apart from that, I think it should be very straight-forward.